# Overwriting TextChannel permissions for every channel in a guild

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently working on a mute function for my bot but so far have only gotten it to set permissions for only the channel the message was sent from.

I tried using the *guild.channels* property but ended up getting nowhere with it, although I'm sure I'm just using it wrong.

```js
var timer = args[1]
var channels = msg.channel

channels.overwritePermissions(msg.mentions.users.first(), { SEND_MESSAGES: false });

msg.reply(`Muted ${msg.mentions.users.first().username} for ${timer} seconds`)

setTimeout(unmute, timer * 1000);

function unmute(){
  channels.overwritePermissions(msg.mentions.users.first(), { SEND_MESSAGES: true });
}
```

I want it to set the SEND_MESSAGES permission for all channels, but it only does so for the one I send the command from.

Answer (score 0):

[Iterate over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) the text channels in the guild.

```js
const channels = message.guild.channels.filter(c => c.type === 'text');

for (let [, channel] of channels) {
//        ^
// Ignoring the key; we don't need it
}
```

Why use a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) when [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) is provided for us? The latter simply calls promises and moves on without ensuring their completion. So, if there's an error, it won't be caught even when a [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method is attached.

---

Overwrite each channels' permissions using [`GuildChannel.overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) (**note:** this method will *replace* permission overwrites on the master branch).

```js
channel.overwritePermissions(msg.mentions.users.first(), { SEND_MESSAGES: false })
  .catch(console.error); // Catch and log errors
```

---

Putting it together...

```js
const channels = message.guild.channels;

for (let [, channel] of channels) {
  channel.overwritePermissions(msg.mentions.users.first(), { SEND_MESSAGES: false })
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! for an auto unmute i ended up setting SEND_MESSAGES to null so people dont type in my announcements.